# file->d_name into a variable in C

Tags: c, variables, filenames

I have a probleme with a program. 
I need to take file name in a folder and put it in a variable. 
I tried that:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#undef _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *file;
  char fileName;
  dir = opendir("../../incoming");

    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    printf("  %s\n", file->d_name);
    fileName = file->d_name;
    printf(fileName);
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

thx

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Is it correctly printing out, but it's not writing to the file? If so, check my answer.

Comment: humm. I want file name into my folder without extension...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very clear what you wanted, I prefer to think you want read the file name into your varible 'fileName' and then handle that varible...
Correct 2 parts:

1. fileName type should be same as the struct member for assign.
2. the while loop......

   ```
   int main(){
     DIR *dir;
     struct dirent *file;
     char fileName[255];
     dir = opendir("../../incoming");
       while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
       {
           printf("  %s\n", file->d_name);
           strncpy(fileName, file->d_name, 254);
           fileName[254] = '\0';
           printf("%s\n", fileName);
       }
       closedir(dir);
   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: What if the string is way shorter than 255?  You can still put that \0 at 254?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a character array of sufficient size and copy the contents of the file->d_name into it if you want to save it past the call to closedir().

If you want to simply print the name,

```
printf("%s\n", file->d_name);
```

would accomplish that.

Comment: It would have been better if the first part of your answer had some supporting code. We already know the process to do it. We do not know how to do it from code point of view (if we need to use memcpy, of char by char, strcpy). the provided code to print the file name, is extremely basic and exists even in the question, and is out of context for the answer.